# How to get shape country (without maritime limit...only terrain) in Overpass?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am trying to get the shape of country in Overpass API without the maritime limit in http://overpass-turbo.eu

And I have this query but it shows the maritime:

```
relation
  ["boundary"="administrative"]
  ["admin_level"="2"]
  ["name:en"="Spain"];
(._;>;);
out body;
```

Answer (score 3):

I found it, thanks to OpenStreetmap spanish mailing list and the doc (it is in spanish) https://iceosm2016.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ .

```
area["name"="España"]->.country;
rel["name"="España"]["type"="boundary"]["admin_level"="2"];
(
way(r)["maritime" != "yes"]({{bbox}});
way(area.country)["natural"="coastline"]({{bbox}});
);
out geom;
```

Comment: From this one can generate a polygon, however it isn't that trivial for all countries, such as the US or Canada. This CLI tool could help on those cases https://github.com/TimMcCauley/nintynine-boundaries

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a dedicated relation for Península ibérica instead:

```
relation
  ["wikidata"="Q12837"];
(._;>;);
out body;
```